# Rails: run private controller methods based on a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to run a certain private controller method based on a variable, thus:

```
def new
  @doc = Doc.new
  #see private methods
  @template.name.parameterize.underscore
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Where `@template.name.parameterize.underscore` will be the exact name of a private method in the same controller. Is that possible? If not is there a way to achieve that?

**UPDATE**

Using this code instead:

```
template = @template.name.parameterize.underscore.to_sym
@doc.send template
```

Gives me a NoMethodError: `undefined method 'newsletter' for #<Doc:blah>` even though I've a private method called `newsletter` in the controller.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: Will that work on controller methods? I get a NoMethodError for everything passed through `send`.

Comment: It'll work for everything - all Ruby method calls are just messages, and send allows you to dispatch an arbitrary message. Are you sure that you're calling send on the right object?

Comment: I'll update my question. It looks to me like it should work.

Comment: Just use `send template` or `self.send template` - the object you want to send the message to (that is, call a method on) is the controller, not your Doc instance.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Any chance you could add this as an answer, that way you could get proper credit (if emm accepts it), and this question would be marked as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send arbitrary messages with the `send` method.

Since you want to send a message from your controller to your controller, you can just use `send template` to invoke the method stored in your `template` variable.